# How can I send a WishList Member Broadcast Email when not admin?

Tags: wordpress, email

I am helping administer a team site for our Speech and Debate club. We have students, parents, and coaches all assigned through WishList Member (including the differation between different student types, which events they are working on).

I do like that with WishList you are able to broadcast email to specific groups of people.  We are asking for volunteers and a few of the parents want to help with sending out homework assignments etc.

The problem I'm running into is that to use WishList broadcast, you need to have WordPress admin status.  Two issues with that are, I don't necessarily want the whole backend open to all volunteers who need to email the groups of students, and, the pages I am creating "break" when someone has admin status (Administrators can see all content, although I'm using different statuses to see different content, and it looks very cluttered if you see both the active button and the inactive button for roles, etc.).

**Core of my question:**
Is there a way to allow people to send emails to a group of people (all members with a specific level), without also giving them WP Admin privileges?